# Adding data to an external database using a php script

Tags: php, android, json

I am trying to run a php script that takes 3 parameters.

Here is my simple script:

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("localhost","login","pass");
    mysql_select_db("android");

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO people (name, sex, birthyear) VALUES ('".$_REQUEST['name']."', ".$_REQUEST['sex'].", ".$_REQUEST['year'].")");

    mysql_close();
?>
```

What am I doing wrong, the program does not return any errors.
And here is the same program:

```
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://mysite.com/addPeople.php");

    try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", "Maciek"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sex", "1"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("year", "1981"));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
```

Comment: Can't see any issue right now. But wanted to mention one important thing: NEVER EVER paste formular/request data 1:1 into any SQL query. Always escape it to avoid code injection attacks. I.e. use `mysql_escape_string($_REQUEST[...])` instead of `$_REQUEST[...]`! Otherwise I could insert the following name and screw you up: `'); drop table people;`

Comment: Mario is right, on one of our first public application we learned this lesson when one of my partners coworkers used a un-escaped text box meant to update a profile about field to edit other fields in other tables.

Comment: If the PHP side is working fine (with the exception of the security holes noted by other SOers), I would suggest running an analyser like Ethereal/Wireshark on a computer attached to the same LAN as your Android device and seeing what HTTP requests are being sent by your Android app. Once you know where the problem is, it can be solved.

Answer (score 0):

you should definitely escape the form data and filter it before passing it into the database. This could really affect the security.

You may [escape the variables with this function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) and then process the query.

Also be sure that the user who is trying to access the database has proper privileges.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem I see is that your mysql call are not specifying a connection will therefore be trying to make an unspecified connection. Try editting that line to:

```
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","login","pass");
mysql_select_db("android", $conn);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO people (name, sex, birthyear) VALUES ('".$_REQUEST['name']."', ".$_REQUEST['sex'].", ".$_REQUEST['year'].")", $conn);
```

We also find it helpful to wrap our mySQL query function inside a helper function:

```
function query($q) {
  global $conn;
  $result = mysql_query($q, $conn);
  if (!$result) {
    die("<b>SQL Error:</b><br>---<b>QUERY:</b> $q<br><br><b>ERROR:</b> " . mysql_error());
  }
  return $result;  
}
```

This allows us to handle errors and we also log the queries including execution time (not show).

Comment: Php script, everything is fine. If I start the browser and I type link:
http://mysite.com/addPeople.php?name=Jagoda&sex=0&year=1700
This data shall be transmitted to the database.
How do I run the program is not added.